# How to show Java dynamic table in main form instead of new generating form

Tags: java, netbeans6.7

I am trying to display a java table on particular event like, when I click button.
It makes a DB connection, gets data, puts it into the table, and shows the table in new window. But I want to display that table in my main form, i.e. itself button frame.

Comment: You want to show the table in a new window and you want to display it in your main form?  At the same time?  If not, what is the criteria you want to use for when you show it in your main form versus in the new window?

Comment: could you illustrate your problem/question with some code you already have? normally you simply need to call buttonFrame.add(table) with an appropriate layout manager and you are done

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Angular-js for this kind of stuff. See `ng-repeat` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).